# Is it permissible to wear tight leggings under over-knee shorts in public?

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah, clothing, fatwa, awrah

Assalamualaikum,
Recently alhamdulillah I started to (try to) apply the Deen as best as possible and I have lots of shorts in my possession that do not cover the awrah properly (are a little over the knee)
As a solution can I wear tight leggings (cover 3/4 of the leg) under those shorts? It's more comfortable than wearing pants and I can still make use of the shorts, but I'm not sure if it's ok for my knee to be viewable in tight clothing publicly.

If it's Haram completely, can I donate these shorts to poor people?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site. Please note we are not a fatwa site. To make yourself familiar with our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are a woman.

Wearing leggins will formally fulfill the prescriptions of traditional fiqh.

I understand the orders about clothing as a means for self-protection of the women. As such it's not absolute but it depends on the society you are living in. In a traditional Islamic society and in India your outfit with leggins will be seen provoking, whereas in Europe or the U.S you would better have your lower legs uncovered in terms of self-protection. This is a common liberal Islamic position that is not supported by traditional fiqh.

Giving to the poor something that you suppose to be haram  is - independently from your particular case- not a good idea. Giving someone something that is not halal is not a good deed.

Comment: There is nothing called liberal Islam. This is as if you're putting poison in honey to conceal its taste!. 
On the other hand, "*Wearing leggins will formally fulfill the prescriptions of traditional fiqh*": Your answer is misleading, please if you don't know the law, don't give fatwa to people because it'll be counted as a bad deed every single time someone does it after reading your answer/fatwa. The proof is in the next comment.

Comment: Abu Hurairah said:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "There are two types of people who will be punished in Hell and whom I have not seen: men having whips like the tails of cows and they will be beating people with them, and, **women who will be dressed but appear to be naked**, inviting to evil; and they themselves will be inclined to it. Their heads will appear like the humps of the Bactrian camel inclined to one side. They will not enter Jannah and they will not smell its fragrance which is perceptible from such and such a distance."

Comment: The Arabic phrase in the aforementioned Hadith is: "Kassyaat Aryaat" which means  "Covered with cloths but as if they are not covered because the cloths are too tight in which the observer can imagine the details of the body of the woman". This exactly describes what the OP has asked.

Comment: @Yahya On the one hand there are some people who declare themselves liberal Muslim. I do not agree with them in many points. On the other hand probably a majority of Muslim here in Europe do not share the strict clothing rules as in Arabia as they are not as evidently a must as it is interpreted by Arabic scholars.

Comment: No one is talking here about fashion or cloth style, every Muslim can wear any style as long as it complies with Sharia, as per the explicit proof I've provided. Lastly, the so called Liberal Islam is not Islam by any means.